# Forward bundle from one intent to another

Tags: android, android-intent, bundle

Is there a way to pass an intent bundle from one intent to another without having to extract the bundle and handle each extra individually?

Example:

```
intent2.setExtras(intent2.getExtras());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a dedicated function

Intent.putExtras(Bundle extras)

Hope this helps
Serge

Comment: I'm not sure how I missed that - but that's exactly what I wanted.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Why not? Given that there exist 3 Activities: ActivityA, ActivityB, and ActivityC...

**Activity A**

```
Intent intentA = new Intent(this,ActivityB.class);
intentA.putExtras(new Bundle());
```

**Activity B**

```
Intent intentB = new Intent(this,ActivityC.class);
intentB.putExtras(getIntent());
```

**Activity C**

```
Intent intentFromA = getIntent();
// Consume and process the Bundle here.
```