# Request permission for Location updates inside IntentService

Tags: java, android, permissions, location

How do I request permission for my location (api 23>) when I want to access the location inside a service?

I have a service running every minute fetching data from a URL. In this service I want to pass my location in the URL but I have issues requesting the permission for my location (*since you cant do that inside a service*). How can I request permission in my `MainActivity`?

**EDIT**: I think my problem is requesting permissions inside a service. My service is started with `alarmManager` (setRepeating), and in this service I want to access my real time location. When I try to request permission there it does not work. Can I request permissions elsewhere?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Request Location Permissions from a service Android M](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33867088/request-location-permissions-from-a-service-android-m)

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** If the app starts for the first time, you can ask the user for permission (from your Activity) - user can grant or deny the permission.

If user has denied the permission you should stop/don't start your service and inform the user that, without this permission, your app doesn't work.

See [Requesting Permissions at Run Time](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13443668)

Comment: That's true, but 30 seconds of searching would have answered his question.