# Trying to request a dialog with the location permission in Android Studio but it doesn't work

Tags: java, android, android-studio, location, google-signin

I'm trying to request a dialog with the location permission to activate it, but I don't know how to do it exactly.. If you can help me, thanks.

This is my full code:

```
public class DialogEntrar extends BlurDialogFragment implements GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
    GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    LocationListener {
private static final String TAG = DialogEntrar.class.getSimpleName();
private SignInButton btnSignInGlg;

static GoogleApiClient apiClient;
private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 1001;



private static final String LOGTAG = "android-localizacion";

private static final int PETICION_PERMISO_LOCALIZACION = 101;
private static final int PETICION_CONFIG_UBICACION = 201;

private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

private View v;

//Datos de usuario entrado
String personName;
String personGivenName;
String personFamilyName;
String personEmail;
String personId;
Uri personPhoto;

public DialogEntrar() {
}

@NonNull
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return createLoginDialogo();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    apiClient.stopAutoManage((FragmentActivity) getActivity());
    apiClient.disconnect();
}

//Lo que sale una vez apretas el boton de jugar
private void showProgressDialog() {
    if (progressDialog == null) {
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        progressDialog.setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.Entrando));
        progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);

    }
    progressDialog.show();
}

private void hideProgressDialog() {
    if (progressDialog != null && progressDialog.isShowing()) {
        progressDialog.hide();
    }
}

public AlertDialog createLoginDialogo() {

    //ROLLO DE LA API DE GOOGLE SIGN IN
    GoogleSignInOptions gso =
            new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                    .requestEmail()
                    .build();

    apiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity())
            .enableAutoManage((FragmentActivity) getActivity(), this)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso).addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();


    //INFLADOR DIALOGO
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_dialog_entrar, null);
    builder.setView(v);


    //BOTON Desconectarse
    Button desconectarse = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btnDialogDesconnect);
    desconectarse.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(apiClient.isConnected()) {
                        Log.i(TAG, String.valueOf(apiClient.isConnected()));
                        desconnectUser();
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), getResources().getString(R.string.Desconectar), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }else if(!apiClient.isConnected()){
                        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                        DialogFragment newFragment = new OneActionDesconectado();
                        newFragment.show(fragmentManager, "TAG");
                    }

                }
            }
    );

    //BOTON CREAR NUEVO USUARIO
    Button btnCrearNewUSU = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.btnDiaUsuNew);
    btnCrearNewUSU.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://accounts.google.com/SignUp?service=mail&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fmail.google.com%2Fmail%2F&hl=es"); // missing 'http://' will cause crashed
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    btnSignInGlg = (SignInButton)v.findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);
    btnSignInGlg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showProgressDialog();
            Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(apiClient);
            startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
            hideProgressDialog();
        }
    });


    return builder.create();
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        handleSignInResult(result);
    }
}

private void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {
    if (result.isSuccess()) {
        //Usuario logueado --> Mostramos sus datos
        GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();

        if(acct.getDisplayName() != null){
            personName = acct.getDisplayName();
        }
        personGivenName = acct.getGivenName();
        personFamilyName = acct.getFamilyName();
        personEmail = acct.getEmail();
        personId = acct.getId();
        personPhoto = acct.getPhotoUrl();

        Log.i(TAG, personName);
        Log.i(TAG, personGivenName);
        Log.i(TAG, personFamilyName);
        Log.i(TAG, personEmail);
        Log.i(TAG, personId);
        Log.i(TAG, String.valueOf(personPhoto));

        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), InicioJuegoActivity.class);

        intent.putExtra("personName", personName);
        intent.putExtra("personGivenName", personGivenName);
        intent.putExtra("personFamilyName", personFamilyName);
        intent.putExtra("personEmail", personEmail);
        intent.putExtra("personId", personId);
        intent.putExtra("personPhoto", String.valueOf(personPhoto));

        startActivity(intent);
        getActivity().finish();
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Conectado",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        hideProgressDialog();

    } else {
        //Usuario no logueado --> Lo mostramos como "Desconectado"
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Desconectado",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}


public void desconnectUser(){
    Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(apiClient).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(Status status) {
                    if(apiClient.isConnected()) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), getResources().getString(R.string.Desconectar), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }else if(apiClient == null){
                        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                        DialogFragment newFragment = new OneActionDesconectado();
                        newFragment.show(fragmentManager, "TAG");
                    }
                }
            });
}

//PERMISSIONS

@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
    //Conectado correctamente a Google Play Services

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(),
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                PETICION_PERMISO_LOCALIZACION);
    } else {

        Location lastLocation =
                LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(apiClient);

        updateUI(lastLocation);
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
    //Se ha interrumpido la conexión con Google Play Services

    Log.e(LOGTAG, "Se ha interrumpido la conexión con Google Play Services");
}

private void updateUI(Location loc) {
    if (loc != null) {
        Log.e(LOGTAG, "Latitud: " + String.valueOf(loc.getLatitude()) + " Longitud: " + String.valueOf(loc.getLongitude()));

    } else {
        Log.e(LOGTAG, "Latitud: (desconocida) Longitud: (desconocida)");

    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    if (requestCode == PETICION_PERMISO_LOCALIZACION) {
        if (grantResults.length == 1
                && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            //Permiso concedido

            @SuppressWarnings("MissingPermission")
            Location lastLocation =
                    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(apiClient);

            updateUI(lastLocation);

        } else {
            //Permiso denegado:
            //Deberíamos deshabilitar toda la funcionalidad relativa a la localización.

            Log.e(LOGTAG, "Permiso denegado");
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    Log.i(LOGTAG, "Recibida nueva ubicación!");

    //Mostramos la nueva ubicación recibida
    updateUI(location);
}
```

It just, don't show the dialog and I don't know why.. If you can help me, thanks..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Request Location Permissions from a service Android M](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33867088/request-location-permissions-from-a-service-android-m)

Comment: @user2025187 it doesnt gives the solution...

Answer (score 0):

The method **onConnected()** is never called because you need to call it by using the method [**connect()**](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient#connect()).

> public abstract void connect ()
>
> Connects the client to Google Play services. This method returns
>   immediately, and connects to the service in the background. If the
>   connection is successful, onConnected(Bundle) is called and enqueued
>   items are executed. On a failure, onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult)
>   is called.
>
> If the client is already connected or connecting, this method does
>   nothing.

*For example in your code you need to include:  **apiClient.connect();***

*[Start a manually managed connection:](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/api-client)*

> *In an activity context the best practice is to call **connect()** in your
>   activity's **onStart()** method and **disconnect()** in your activity's
>   **onStop()** method.*

Comment: I put apiclient.connect() in the createLoginDialog() and it don't call the permission..

Comment: hmm you called `apiClient.connect()` **after** the initialization _(`apiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(....)`)_ and didn't work?