# Requesting Permission from service. Android M

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow

I am working on Android Permission for M.

In my app in my activity I am starting a service, where I am using following code for Camera.

**Code for Opening Camera in Service**

`cameraManager.openCamera(frontFacingCameraId, stateCallback, null);`

I checked some documentations and i found that I cant request permission in service, I need to ask the permission in activity. So I am asking the permission in my activity.

**Activity where requesting permission**

`if (PermissionUtil.getCameraPermission(this)) {
                    Debug.d(TAG, "Camera Permission -- permission exsited");
                    performRecordingAction();
                }`

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case PermissionUtil.SDK__CAMERA_PERMISSION:
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Debug.d(TAG, "Granted -- Camera Permission");
                performRecordingAction();
            } else {
                Debug.d(TAG, "Denied -- Camera Permission");
                // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                // functionality that depends on this permission.
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

**PermissionUtil**

```
public static boolean getCameraPermission(Activity activity) {
    Debug.d(TAG, "getCameraPermission");
    int permission = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.CAMERA);

    if (permission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(activity, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)) {
            Debug.d(TAG, "Already Denied -- Camera Permission");
            return false;
        } else {
            Debug.d(TAG, "Request Camera Permission");
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, SDK__CAMERA_PERMISSION);
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

But in service at above line it is still throwing error for security exception.

Can anyone suggest where I am making mistake? And is there any way to request permission from service?

Comment: Share your code please. With this much information it's anyone's guess. Unless you want the answer to be that your are not requesting the permissions correctly..

Comment: ask for permission in activity before start service!

Answer (score 2):

You can not request permissions from a Service as you need an Activity context for the callback provided by the system. Also the permission request is running asynchronously from your app.
See also the docs from **requestPermissions()** [>>LINK](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#requestPermissions(java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20int)):

> This method may start an activity allowing the user to choose which
> permissions to grant and which to reject. Hence, you should be
> prepared that your activity may be paused and resumed. Further,
> granting some permissions may require a restart of you application. In
> such a case, the system will recreate the activity stack before
> delivering the result to onRequestPermissionsResult(int, String[],
> int[]).

A service can only check if he has the required permissions at runtime and then adapt his behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `android:exported="true"` in your manifest file as follows :

```
<activity
android:name="com.example.MainActivity"
android:label="Main" 
android:exported="true">
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" >
    </action>
</intent-filter>
```

It will solve problem of Security Exception.

**Is there any way to request permission from service?**

Ya, follow [Requesting permission from service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32292675/how-to-request-permissions-from-a-service-in-android-marshmallow)

Answer (score 0):

As it is neccessary to check permissions inline in android SDK 23 (and later) you can ignore the `shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale` (which prompt user to set permission) and just check if permission was granted before:

```
public boolean checkPermission(){
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 23) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
            //        android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA)) {
            //    PropmtForPermission();
            //} else {

                return false;
            //}
        }
        else{
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```