# Dexter Library for Android permission handling always is always triggering callback onPermissionDenied

Tags: android, permissions

I trying to handle the new permission model in Android version 23 using the library called Dexter:

https://github.com/Karumi/Dexter

Problem is that if i need to check permission access to **SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW** callback onPermissionDenied is always called without the displaying the permission dialog.

```
PermissionListener dialogPermissionListener = new PermissionListener() {
                @Override public void onPermissionGranted(PermissionGrantedResponse response) {
                    Logger.d("onPermissionGranted");
                }
                @Override public void onPermissionDenied(PermissionDeniedResponse response) {
                    Logger.d("onPermissionDenied");

                }

                @Override public void onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(PermissionRequest permission, PermissionToken token) {
                    Logger.d("onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown");
                }
            };

            Dexter.checkPermission(dialogPermissionListener, Manifest.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW);
```

How can i do permission check in the right way?

**Note:** Permission check is processed in the service, not in the Activity because service should to display SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW above the all other windows in the app (is permission is granted).

Many thanks for any advice.

Comment: Have you tried to change the `checkPermission` method to `checkPermissionOnSameThread`? I suspect that you are receiving the callback in a different thread since you are using a Service.

Also, this might be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32292675/how-to-request-permissions-from-a-service-in-android-marshmallow

Answer (score 2):

You should also add the permissions in the AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 2):

> Permissions SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW and WRITE_SETTINGS are considered special by Android. Dexter doesn't handle those and you'll need to request them in the old fashioned way.

[Already mentioned here in the lib itself][1]
https://github.com/Karumi/Dexter#caveats