# Android M onRequestPermissionsResult in non-Activity

Tags: java, android, android-6.0-marshmallow

I have an application which needs to find the user **location**, and location is fetched in various classes, so i have written a separate class(Not an Activity class) that fetches user location using **location services**, it works fine under **Android M** but requires run time permissions in **Android M**, i want to check permissions in my Location class and i know how to check them but i cannot use **onRequestPermissionsResult** method in my Location class, because my Location class do not extends from any activity.

So What i should do for achieving this? any help/clue is appreciated
Thanks in advance

Comment: You just need to get the permission before you need it. It doesn't necessarily have to be right when you need it. Just ask the user for it from one of your Activities, wherever that might be appropriate.

Comment: @MikeM. do i need to check permission in some Activity/Fragment? basically i am checking permission in my Location class

Comment: You can _check_ for a permission wherever you have access to a `Context`, which you presumably would in your `Location` class, so that's fine, and also exactly what you should be doing there.

Comment: @MikeM. Yes i do have context my Location class but how do i override onRequestPermissionsResult

Comment: requestPermission() can only be called from an Activity and not a Service (unlike checkPermission() that only requires PackageManager). check this answer for more details http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32292675/how-to-request-permissions-from-a-service-in-android-marshmallow

Comment: You wouldn't. `onRequestPermissionsResult()` follows from a `requestPermissions()` call, which, as we said, you should be doing in your `Activity`, not in the `Location` class. There is no callback for `checkSelfPermission()`.

Comment: @MikeM. thanks for clearing things up

Comment: No problem. Yeah, you should listen to CommonsWare. You probably wanna check for the permission before you even create your `Location` class instance, so there's really no need to even just check from there.

Comment: I Just found two Solutions:
1-you must override the onRequestPermissionsResult in your Activity where you calling that non activity class
2-you can repeat call function of request permission and call your get location function inside it after request permission.

Comment: I Just found two Solutions: 
1-you must override the onRequestPermissionsResult in your Activity where you calling that non activity class 
2-you can repeat call function of request permission and call your get location function inside it after request permission.

Answer (score 21):

Since  **public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           String permissions[], int[] grantResults)** is an abstract method of **ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback** interface. 
See
[the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback.html)

Just implement this interface in the required class and it's done.
For example

```
class location implements  ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback{ }
```

Now just override **onRequestPermissionsResult()**

```
 @Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
     // case Statements
    }
}
```

Comment: In theory yes, but android doesn't seems to call onRequestPermissionsResult on non activity class.

Comment: @mauron85 when you implement OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback  interface in any non-activity class, you will surly get onRequestPermissionsResult method.

Comment: well, that can't be true since `requestPermissions()` needs `Activity` as a parameter, not just a class implementing `OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback`

Comment: I did this but it dosen't work so this answer is useless

Comment: It's not about adding the method to service and overriding, it's about getting the method called from the system.

Comment: Come on, you are creating a new object implementing a similar interface implemented by the Activity and expect it to call the callback? The OS only knows about the Activity implementing the interface and nothing else.

Comment: when a method (A) calls an interface (B) callback (C) if  A have a parametre referring to B then the callback C will be called otherwise C couldn't be called.
for the method requestPermissions() it uses activity as a parametre not ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback so it's not possible to use this at all

Answer (score 12):

You are welcome to call `checkSelfPermission()` from a non-UI class, as that merely needs some `Context`.

However, you must call `requestPermissions()` on some activity or fragment. You override `onRequestPermissionsResult()` on that *same* activity or fragment. This is no different than calling `startActivityForResult()` and implementing `onActivityResult()`.

The idea is that you request the permission before you do anything that involves your non-UI classes that are dealing with locations.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i know this approach, but i basically wanted to override onRequestPermissionsResult() in non-activity class. and now i guess it is not possible

Comment: @Tahir: Correct. You are welcome to have the activity or fragment call into your non-UI class to provide the results of the permission request. Preferably, the non-activity class instance does not even exist, though -- you request and confirm the permission before creating that `Location` instance and trying to do things with the location data.

Comment: @CommonsWare,  In that case, is there any way that I can get the context in onRequestPermissionsResult()  in non UI-class ?

Comment: @NoorHossain: As I wrote in the answer, "You override `onRequestPermissionsResult()` on that *same* activity or fragment." I am going to interpret "non UI-class" as meaning something other than an activity or fragment. If you decide to implement a method named `onRequestPermissionsResult()` on a "non UI-class", you are responsible for calling that method yourself. And, therefore, you can pass whatever parameters you like, such as a `Context`.

Comment: @CommonsWare, thanks for quick and great reply,  - regards.

Answer (score 5):

1- create a transparent activity

```
<activity android:name=".activity.activity.CheckStoragePermissionsActivity" android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent">

<style name="Theme.Transparent" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
        <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
    </style>
```

2- customize your activity

```
public class CheckStoragePermissionsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private String[] permissions;
    private int pCode = 12321;
    public static PermissionListener permissionListener;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        checkPermissions();
    }

    private void checkPermissions() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {

            permissions = new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};

            boolean flag = false;
            for (String s : permissions)
                if (checkSelfPermission(s) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                    flag = true;

            if (flag) {
                requestPermissions(permissions, pCode);
            } else {
                permissionListener.permissionResult(true);
                finish();
            }
        }else
            finish();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode == pCode) {
            boolean flag = true;
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
                for (int i = 0, len = permissions.length; i < len; i++)
                    if (grantResults[i] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                        flag = false;
            if (flag) {
                if (permissionListener != null)
                    permissionListener.permissionResult(true);
            } else if (permissionListener != null)
                permissionListener.permissionResult(false);
            finish();
        }
    }
}
```

3- `permissionListener` is an static interface and can be set directly before context.startActivity(...), or use your plan to found permission result.

```
public interface PermissionListener extends Serializable {
    void permissionResult(boolean hasPermission);
}
```

4- finally call `context.startActivity(new Intent(context, CheckStoragePermissionsActivity.class));`

`CheckStoragePermissionsActivity` do all of needed and finish after user Allow or Deny action.

Comment: Just FYI, Its not mandatory to check for permission in Activity. You can still do it with just context instance from anywhere using ContextCompat class. You can even avoid lot of version checks if you use ContextCompat class.

Comment: @Ayyappa onRequestPermissionsResult is not called if we dont do it in Activity

Answer (score 4):

You can not override it. This method is only available for Activity and Fragments. But you can create a static method inside your Location class and call it from your activity/fragment's overridden onRequestPermissionResult method.

I have made a custom implementation for Location combined with permission. You can also use a library called Let for permissions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, after reading all the answers/comments now i know that i must use this onRequestPermissionResult() in some Activity/Fragment.

Answer (score 0):

probably you can create a class that extends Activity (AppCompactActivity is better), implement all needed location code and extends with this class all activities where you need to use it.

Answer (score -1):

use this class :

```
public class permissionModule {

final public static int STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE = 23;
private Activity activity;

public permissionModule(Activity activity) {
    this.activity = activity;
}

public void startGetPermission(){
    if (isStorageReadable()){
        Toast.makeText(activity,"you Already have the permission to access storage",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }else {
        requestStoragePermission();
    }
}

private void requestStoragePermission() {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE);
}

private boolean isStorageReadable() {
    int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, 

Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        return result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
    }
}
```

and in your activity call :

```
new permissionModule(MainActivity.this).startGetPermission();
```

finally for result , override this in your activity :

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    if (requestCode == permissionModule.STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE) {
        if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Snackbar permissionWarning = Snackbar.make(rootLayout, "tnk", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);
            permissionWarning.setAction("ok", new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    //...
                }
            });
            permissionWarning.show();
        } else {
            boolean showRationale = shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
            if (showRationale) {
                Snackbar permissionWarning = Snackbar.make(rootLayout, "Permission Required to access storage", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);
                permissionWarning.setAction("ok", new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        //requestStoragePermission();
                    }
                });
                permissionWarning.show();
            } else {
                Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(rootLayout, "you denied the permission for ever pleas fix it in setting", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);
                snackbar.setAction("setting", new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent();
                        intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
                        Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package", MainActivity.this.getPackageName(), null);
                        intent.setData(uri);
                        MainActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });
                snackbar.show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```