# Missing permissions required by LocationManager

Tags: android, android-permissions

Android Studio 3.4.

A device on android 6.0

in manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.myproject">


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_GPS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="md.qsystems.android.tango.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
    <!-- MAP -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
```

In my simple class (no activity/fragment) I have:

```
public class LocationHelper {

if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)) {
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locListener);
            }
```

I have compile error:

```
Missing permissions required by LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates: android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION or android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION 

}
```

Comment: have you added these permissions in manifest ?

Comment: Yes, but it not help

Comment: See https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting. Also note that there is no `ACCESS_GPS` permission, and that the `GET_TASKS` permission is ignored, so you can remove those.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call this checkAndRequestPermissions() Method whenevr you want permission

```
public boolean checkAndRequestPermissions() {
    int internet = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext, 
    Manifest.permission.INTERNET);
    int loc = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext, 
    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION);
    int loc2 = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext, 
    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
    List<String> listPermissionsNeeded = new ArrayList<>();

    if (internet != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.INTERNET);
    }
    if (loc != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION);
    }
    if (loc2 != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
    }
    if (!listPermissionsNeeded.isEmpty()) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) mContext, listPermissionsNeeded.toArray
                (new String[listPermissionsNeeded.size()]), 1);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to have both of those permissions to your manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

So check your manifest file and make sure that you have both of them.

Comment: Tamir you're answer is right but sometime it will problematic with some sdkVersion

Answer (score 1):

**Add ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION and ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION in AndroidManifest File**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

**Ask for permission at runtime to use device current location as below :**

```
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(YourActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(YourActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
      ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(YourActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1);
      return;
}else{
  // Write you code here if permission already given.
  // Call LocationHelper 
}
```

**Handle when user allow to use device current location or not :**

```
   @Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
        String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
           if (grantResults.length > 0  && grantResults[0] == 
       PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
       // Write you code here if permission already given.
       // Call LocationHelper 
}                           }else{
                        // you must ask location permission again
                        }
}
```

Comment: It's simple class. Not AppCompatActivity. How I can override onRequestPermissionsResult ?

Comment: Please Check this question:  onRequestPermissionsResult in non-Activity? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38480671/android-m-onrequestpermissionsresult-in-non-activity