# How to get Runtime Permission from Anywhere in android application like Recyclarview Adapter

Tags: android

I know how to request runtime permission in activity but i want to know how to Request Runtime permission for adapter Or from any where in my android Application.

blow is my code of recyclarview adapter

```
public class MoviesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MoviesAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
private List<Movie> moviesList;

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView title, year, genre;

    public MyViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
        genre = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.genre);
        year = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.year);
    }
}


public MoviesAdapter(List<Movie> moviesList) {
    this.moviesList = moviesList;
}

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.movie_list_row, parent, false);

    return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Movie movie = moviesList.get(position);
    holder.title.setText(movie.getTitle());
    holder.genre.setText(movie.getGenre());
    holder.year.setText(movie.getYear());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return moviesList.size();
}
}
```

Thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Runtime Permission AnyWhere In Application** find [Here](https://github.com/irshadsparky/PermissionExample)

you can easily inaugurate this library by using :

```
use dependency
maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
dependencies {
implementation 'com.github.irshadsparky:PermissionLib:master-SNAPSHOT'}
```

and call code like this :

```
PermissionHelper.requestCamera(new PermissionHelper.OnPermissionGrantedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPermissionGranted() {

    }
});
```

you can find more

[Github](https://github.com/irshadsparky/PermissionExample)

Comment: yes it is work from anywhere from app like services, activitys,fregments just modify as your requirement

Answer (score 0):

Implement `ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback` in your adapter class so it will ask to implement method `onRequestPermissionsResult`

```
public class MoviesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MoviesAdapter.MyViewHolder> implements ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback{


@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {

}
```

Comment: @rinku, for service, please refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32293613/4748607)