# Wait until permisison request result received in Android

Tags: android

I've seen SO question *[Can you request permissions synchronously in Android Marshmallow (API 23)'s runtime permissions model?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32134299/3278063)*. The answer is no.

Hence, I added a code as below (simplified version):

```
public class MyActivity ... {
    private boolean hasGotPermissionRequestResult = false;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(...) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(...) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermission(...);
            while (!hasGotPermissionRequestResult) {}
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionResult(...) {
        // whether granted or not
        hasGotPermissionRequestResult = true;
    }
}
```

However, I am not sure whether my approach is nice, safe and efficient.

Comment: `while (!hasGotPermissionRequestResult) {}` in `onCreate` ? ... basically it is not nice neither safe neither efficient ... and prolly will not work

Comment: Rule of thumb: never use busy waiting loops. Especially not on the UI thread

Answer (score 0):

Well, what you trying to achieve simply ain't possible, however there are several ways to overcome this:

1. Only trigger the method you wanna call when the `permission` is granted.
2. If you'd like to make the User only uses your app because that particular `permission` is so important that your app will not `function` without it, then use an educated screen to tell the users why you would want to use this `permission` in an intro screen kinda way.

I've created a library just for this kind of scenario where the `library` simplify the `Permissions` for you, it can be also used as a stand Alone `Activity` that has an Intro to your `permission`. you could check it out in Github [PermissionHelper Github](https://github.com/k0shk0sh/PermissionHelper)